# Utility to Create DBML

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is anyone aware of a free utility, preferably with source code, that will create a Linq-to-SQL DBML based on the contexts of a SQL Server database? I realize Visual Studio can create one, but I don't want to have to drag hundreds of tables onto the L2S canvas just to create a DBML.

Thanks very much - Randy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) is the command-line tool for generating LINQ to SQL DBMLs, and is installed with Visual Studio or as part of the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this. I'm hoping to find a utility with source code.